# trouble with R packages on linux

Tags: software-installation, libraries, r

Why do I have to almost always install libraries and can't install an R package directly as on Windows?

When installing a package named Hyfo, I have to install the libraries of three different dependencies manually. It take me a lot of time looking for the name of the libraries to install so that way I can install Hyfo correctly.

For example for the rgdal package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

How can I know what to install every time a package "had non-zero status"?

I have Lubuntu-based Peppermint OS 7.

Comment: "as on windows?" => because the developers of those packages just hammer the needed libraries inside their binary distriutions instead of following OS standards and documenting their dependency tree?  A lack of documentation which in turn leave packagers unable to make proper dependency trees when packaging it for POSIX compliant OSes.

Comment: Downvote, ok     -__-

Comment: The downvote is not mine.  But nevertheless, one of the main reasons that numpy/scipy is becoming more popular than R is because the packagers of numpy/scipy extensions are much better at making proper dpendency trees for their packages.  Seriously, the R guys need to learn that there's more to software than: "it works for me so it is good enough".  Yes, I have been there with R.

Comment: Thats really bad, R is a really versatile program, usefull for any task involving data. 80% of the time I spent using Windows 10 is using R. But ill keep trying to get used to use R on linux with all the issues involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is not windows. There is a fundamental difference between the two.

In Linux, a proper install of applications is supposed to follow something like this document. http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

It's supposed to allow the sharing of libraries and "code" so that, for example, your music player and your movie player can both use the same "make sounds" library.

Windows "can" do this too, but often does not. More commonly executables in windows are packaged with their dependencies.  In Linux just the executable is packaged. Libraries are marked as dependencies. Systems like apt are there to auto resolve these dependancies. Your "R" package is probably just poorly defined, or not installed via apt.

So either use apt to install packages, or use your package installer to find and install dependances.

Ruby's bundler does a good job of this.  R is apparently giving you problems.

You can not install a package via one package manager, and expect the other to know about it's dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand now, But i have to install the last version of R using .tar.gz file because when I used sudo apt-get it was installed the previous version.